# pyInstaller creates a huge dist folder

Tags: conda, pyinstaller, executable

I recently had to reinstall pyinstaller (I use version 4.4).
I used command

```
pip install pyinstaller==4.4/
```

I run it with a .spec file.

I can see that in the dist folder, my executables are huge (20 MB each) and many folders are stored, like PyQt5, matplotlib,... However, I do not use them in my python files.

The libraries I use are stored in a `venv/Lib/site-packages` under my project folder.
This folder is specified as additional resource in my spec file.

Before, my executables had a size of around 5 MB each, and I only found directories corresponding to the librairies I used in my project.

Could you please explain me what I did wrong, and how I can get rid of these extra files and folders ?

THank you in advance for your help.

Best regards,
Jean-Luc.

Comment: https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html

-F, --onefile
Create a one-file bundled executable.

Should not use dist

Comment: You've answered your own question, haven't you? You store all your libraries in a venv and you tell PyInstaller to package every library in the venv, regardless of whether your program uses them.

Comment: Thank you for all these responses.<br><br> 
@Starbuck5<br> 
I was perhaps not clear enough. I created my venv using PyCharm for my project (let's call it MyProject), and I installed all my necessary libraries using pip. Even if I activate my venv using venv\Scripts\activate from MyProject location, and run pyinstaller inside venv environement, I get a huge dist. 
My PYTHONPATH environment variable refers to site-packages in MyProject/venv and is used by Pyinstaller.

It worked fine before.

Do you have any clue on that ? 
Thanks in advance for your help. 

Best regards, 
Jean-Luc.